# Solving an equation with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, equation

I have a problem with solving this equation:

```
ra = (1.5 * (ca - (ra/2))/(1 + 0.8 * (ca - (ra/2))))
```

I have to enter variable "**ca**" as a float and then python must find me the value of "**ra**"

Thanks in advance

Comment: OK. So what do you want us to do? Do your homework for you?

Comment: That's what most people asking their first question here want...

Comment: Use a different tool like WolframAlpha.com, Maple, Octave, Matlab

Comment: I'm a complete beginner in Python and have no idea how to solve this :/

Comment: I have to disagree, @Galax.  I look at a lot of questions here, and I would say that only a small minority are requests for help with homework.

Comment: @DougR. yeah I'm working on Chemistry project where we have to solve enzyme kinetics equations with Python :)

Comment: first notice ra is on both sides - try solving for ra algebraicly then you can program it

Comment: @IEMSlovenia - I wasn't saying that YOURS wasn't homework (it smelled very much like homework), just saying that only a small minority ARE a request for help for homework. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do things like this with the `sympy` library.

http://docs.sympy.org/dev/index.html

```
>>> from sympy import *
>>> from sympy.solvers import solve

>>> ca, ra = symbols("ca ra")

>>> eq = -ra + (1.5 * (ca - (ra/2))/(1 + 0.8 * (ca - (ra/2))))

>>> print(eq)
-ra + (1.5*ca - 0.75*ra)/(0.8*ca - 0.4*ra + 1)

>>> solutions = solve(eq, ra)  #solve equation for ra
>>> print(solutions)
[ca - 0.0625*sqrt(256.0*ca**2 + 160.0*ca + 1225.0) + 2.1875,
 ca + 0.0625*sqrt(256.0*ca**2 + 160.0*ca + 1225.0) + 2.1875]

>>> values = [s.replace(ca, 5) for s in solutions]  #get solutions for ca=5

[1.45076257791068, 12.9242374220893]
```

Obviously you'll need to get a number from your user for `ca` instead of just solving for `ca=5`.

Answer (score 1):

You're using "ra" in the definition of "ra". You should get rid of the "ra" s on the right side by solving this equation(you can use different tools like wolframalpha or matlab or your paper and pen).

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to find a way to get your value entered into `ca` and assert that it is a float.

`input` is frequently used for such purposes in command line applications (working in a terminal), though you'll want to look into `raw_input` if you're using an earlier Python interpreter.

something like:

`ca = input('Please type a float: ')`

This should get you started. You will need to assert that `ca` is a float (check out `assert` as a possible option for handling this situation).

Then you should create a function which takes `ca` as an argument and outputs `ra`

Something like

```
def calculate(n):
    ...
    return x
```

Comment: In order to turn input into a float, you need to convert it using `float()`. `input()` only ever returns a string in Python 3.

Comment: I know how to work with functions, files, and other stuff in python like (dicts, sets, lists) but I really don't know how to solve this problem :/